# Contar número de linhas de tabelas diferentes fazendo LEFT JOIN usando a função count()

Tags: sql, postgresql

Eu preciso contar o número de registros das tabelas `cliques` e `curtidas` e mostrar esses números para o tipo de mídia `Video` da tabela `tipo_midia` e a mídia específica, ou seja, o vídeo que a pessoa curtiu ou clicou, da tabela `videos`.

```
videos
+--+----------+--------------+
|id| titulo   |id_tipo_midia |
+-------------+--------------+
|01| video_01 | 01           |
|02| video_02 | 01           |
|03| video_03 | 01           |
|04| video_04 | 01           |
+-------------+--------------+

cliques
+--------------+--------+------------+
|id_tipo_midia |id_midia| data_acesso| 
+--------------+--------+------------+
|01            | 03     | 2019-06-03 |
|01            | 03     | 2019-06-03 |
|03            | 01     | 2019-06-05 |
+--------------+--------+------------+

curtidas
+--------------+--------+------------+
|id_tipo_midia |id_midia| data_acesso| 
+--------------+--------+------------+
|01            | 03     | 2019-06-03 |
|01            | 03     | 2019-06-03 |
|01            | 01     | 2019-06-05 |
+--------------+--------+------------+

tipo_midia
+--+-------+
|id| tipo  |
+----------+
|01| Vídeo |
|02| Audio |
|03| Imagem|
+----------+
```

Minha query:

```
select tipo_midia.tipo, videos.titulo, count(cliques.id_midia), count(curtidas.id_midia) from tipo_midia
left join videos on (tipo_midia.id = videos.id_tipo_midia)
left join cliques on (videos.id = cliques.id_midia)
left join curtidas on (videos.id = curtidas.id_midia)
where tipo_midia.id = '1'
group by 1, 2
```

A query deve me retornar:

```
*---------*---------*--------*---------*
|tipoMidia| titulo  | cliques| curtidas|
*---------*---------*--------*---------*
|video    |video_03 | 2      | 2       |
|video    |video_01 | 1      | 0       |
*---------*---------*--------*---------*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar uma sub-query:

```
select 
    tipo_midia.tipo, 
    videos.titulo, 
    (select count(cliques.id_midia) from cliques where cliques.id_midia = videos.id) as cliques, 
    (select count(curtidas.id_midia) from curtidas where curtidas.id_midia = videos.id) as curtidas
from tipo_midia
inner join videos on (tipo_midia.id = videos.id_tipo_midia)
```

Comment: Vc sabe porque nesse caso não dá pra usar a função count() mais de uma vez sem usar sub-querys?

Comment: é uma função de agregação que conta o número de linhas do resultado da query que seguem uma condição. Se você precisa contar as linhas com condições diferentes, tem que ser em duas (ou mais) queries; por isso a subquery. Leitura: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-count-function/

Answer (score 1):

Alguns possíveis erros na sua estrutura de tabela:

- Por que uma tabela `videos` se você já tem uma tabela relacionada `tipo_midia`?
- Por que repetir `id_tipo_ midia` nas tabelas `cliques` e `curtidas`?
- Se não usa hora, usuário, etc, por que não faz um acumulado por data?

---

Sob essas condições, a solução que eu usaria, primeiramente seria simplificar as tabelas:

Tabela `videos` irá virar `registros`, pois você tem uma tabela `tipo_midia` que identifica o tipo de arquivo:

```
registros
+--+----------+--------------+
|id| titulo   |id_tipo_midia |
+-------------+--------------+
|01| vid_01   |     01       |
|02| vid_02   |     01       |
|03| img_01   |     03       |
|04| aud_01   |     02       |
+-------------+--------------+
```

Tabela `cliques` e `curtidas`, serão a mesma tabela, com um acumulado por `data_acesso`, assim economizar muito registro desnecessário, já que você não linka usuário nem hora ao clique:

```
cliques_curtidas
+--------------+--------+--------+------------+
|id_midia      |cliques |curtidas| data_acesso| 
+--------------+--------+--------+------------+
|01            | 95     | 65     | 2019-06-03 |
|01            | 17     | 11     | 2019-06-04 |
|02            | 59     | 37     | 2019-06-03 |
+--------------+--------+--------+------------+
```

Tabela `tipo_midia` mantém:

```
tipo_midia
+--+-------+
|id| tipo  |
+----------+
|01| Vídeo |
|02| Audio |
|03| Imagem|
+----------+
```

---

Posteriormente, o máximo que teria que fazer, é um `SUM` por `id_midia` da tabela `cliques_curtidas`:

```
SELECT tipo, titulo, SUM(cliques), SUM(curtidas)
FROM cliques_curtidas cc
LEFT JOIN tipo_midia tm ON tm.id = cc.id_tipo_midia 
GROUP BY id_midia
```

Comment: Se eu quisesse linkar usuário e data/hora acesso para saber quantidade de cliques e curtidas por usuários, como ficaria?

Comment: Aí neste caso você não teria valor de clique/curtida acumulados, e nem agrupar por data de acesso ou midia. Você poderia ainda sim ter somente 1 tabela `cliques_curtidas`, adicionar um campo `usuário` que seria FK de uma tabela de cadastro de usuários, e um campo único "cliques_curtidas" que usaria um valor pra saber o tipo, se é clique ou curtida. Há diversas formas, tudo depende do seu uso.